# How do I give default values to options to a widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, default-value, jquery-widgets

I have a jQuery widget. I want to define some default values to the options I can send as input.
Is there an intrinsic way to do it, or do I have to manually check if each option has a value, and if not set to default?

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.asyncform", {
        url: '',
        _init: function() {
            this.url = this.options.url || 'my/default/value';

        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

Typcially you'll use `$.extend` to merge default options into your settings object:

```
var settings = $.extend( {
  'location'         : 'top',
  'background-color' : 'blue'
}, options);
```

This is more or less standard, as defined in [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).